# How to use an explicit cast to suppress this warning?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

The following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

int main() {
    int64_t first = 0, last = 10;
    std::vector<double> result = boost::copy_range<std::vector<double>>(boost::irange(first, last));
}
```

generates the warning (and 100+ lines of templated call stack trace):

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0(600):
warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'double', possible loss of data
```

I want to tell the compiler that I don't care that my `int64_t` are being converted to `double`. I also do not want to use a 32-bit int instead. I would usually use `static_cast<double>(my64BitInt)` to solve this, but that won't work for a range. Right now I'm resorting to compiler pragmas to suppress the warning but that's not ideal.

Edit: Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gTVXEbbK) with the full compiler output.

Comment: 1) You can suppress warnings in your project settings rather than with pragmas, if you think you'll never care about this. 2) Why are `first` and `last` declared as `int64_t` instead of `double`?

Comment: @celticminstrel pragmas in Visual Studio allow you to suppress warning on particular lines of code and leave them in place for the rest of the project.

Comment: I'm aware. (You can do it with clang/gcc too, though the syntax is a bit different.) I was just pointing it out partly because I personally find that particular warning to be useless more often than useful and partly in case you happened to agree.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) rather than the boost copy_range. Also, I much prefer using the [boost numeric cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html#boost_numericconversion.improved_numeric_cast__.examples) over the built-in `static_cast`.

Here is a working example:

```
template <class DST, class SRC>
struct Convert
{
    DST operator()(SRC s) { return boost::numeric_cast<DST>(s); }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int64_t first = 0, last = 10;
    auto my_range = boost::irange(first, last);
    std::vector<double> result(my_range.size());
    std::transform(my_range.begin(), my_range.end(), result.begin(), Convert<double, int64_t>());

    std::cout << "result: ";
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));

}
```

The above code uses `transform` with the functor `Convert`. If you prefer a lambda, this works (and is more succinct) too:

```
std::transform(my_range.begin(), my_range.end(), result.begin(), 
               [](int64_t ival) {
                   return boost::numeric_cast<double>(ival);
               }
               );
```

**EDIT Add** iota variant too

As sehe points out, to generate a vector of doubles in the range [0, 10), you can use the [std library iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) (from [#include numeric](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric)) function. Here is a complete (and much shorter) iota example that does not need boost:

```
std::vector<double> result(10);
std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), 0.0);
std::cout << "result: ";
std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
```

Thank you, sehe, for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

what Phil said;

However in this case, you could do much simpler using [the iota algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> result(10);
    boost::iota(result, 0);
}
```